# Mono's equivalent to .NET Framework Debugging Control

Tags: .net, mono

The fusion workshop explains about the [.NET Framework Debugging Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x%28VS.80%29.aspx) .ini file setting.  I think this is only for .NET. Is there any equivalence to mono for debugging control?

```
[.NET Framework Debugging Control]
GenerateTrackingInfo=1
AllowOptimize=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Mono's documentation lists the [`DebuggableAttribute`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aSystem.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/%2a) class that contains these attributes. `DebuggableAttribute` is linked to from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x.aspx) which describes creating an ini file using the exact settings you mention above.

So Mono appears to let you query these values at runtime, although I cannot confirm whether Mono will support the ini file approach. Have you tried testing it?